# Connecting GitHub to Shiny Server

Tags: git, github, shiny-server

I am trying to set up a shiny server with the [manual of Dean Attali](http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/). So far I made the shiny server work. This should be proofed by the fact that the "Welcome to Shiny Server" page shows up when I navigate to the server ip. The problem is that I cannot connect my shiny server to GitHub like in step 8.2 of the manual. I tried it a several times now, but I am getting this error message:

> error: src refspec master does not match any.
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

This is my code:

```
sudo apt-get -y install git
cd /srv/shiny-server
git init
echo "# shiny-server" >> README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git config --global user.email "user@user.com"
git config --global user.name "gituser"
git remote add origin git@github.com:gituser/shiny-server.git
```

The email address "user@user.com" and the user name "gituser" are just dummies.

I already deployed the fitting key in the repository settings in GitHub.

Hope that you can help me! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a step missing here:

> ```
> git init
> echo "# shiny-server" >> README.md
> git commit -m "first commit"
> ```

The missing step is a `git add`, to add the `README.md` to Git.

Without the `git add` step, `git commit` did nothing. As such, the repository doesn't have any commits, and therefore there's nothing to push,
resulting in the error that you observed.

This way it will work:

```
git init
echo "# shiny-server" >> README.md
git add --all
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Comment: thanks for your first advice. I changed this in my code, but now I have two new errors (I edited my post). Could you help me again pls? :)

Comment: It's not clear what you changed, and what are the "two new errors". But your update invalidates my answer: with your change my answer makes no sense now.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to SO! :( Changed it again! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @fexjoo thanks for that. If you post your new question with the new errors, I'll try to take a look (or somebody else will)