# Connecting GitHub to Shiny Server (follow up)

Tags: linux, git, github, shiny-server

I am trying to set up a shiny server with the [manual of Dean Attali](http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/). So far I made the shiny server work. This should be proofed by the fact that the "Welcome to Shiny Server" page shows up when I navigate to the server ip. The problem is that I cannot connect my shiny server to GitHub like in step 8.2 of the manual. I tried it a several times now, but I am getting this error message:

> error: src refspec master does not match any.
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:gituser/shiny-server.git'

This is my code:

```
sudo apt-get -y install git
cd /srv/shiny-server
git init
echo "# shiny-server" >> README.md
git add --all
git commit -m "first commit"
git config --global user.email "user@user.com"
git config --global user.name "gituser"
git remote add origin git@github.com:gituser/shiny-server.git
git push -u origin master
```

The email address "user@user.com" and the user name "gituser" are just dummies.

I already deployed the fitting key in the repository settings in GitHub.

Hope that you can help me! Thanks in advance :)

(This is a follow up question to: [Connecting GitHub to Shiny Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313235/connecting-github-to-shiny-server).)

Comment: It still looks as though your repository in `/src/shiny-server` has no commits. Do you see the output of your code? That output is likely the key to solving your problems.

Comment: Do you mean the normal output you get while writing the code (like the error messages)? I only get the "fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@user-ShinyServer.(none)')"-message after writing the first commit. But I think this is solved with the following two code lines.